# Reset SelectedItem in LongListSelector after selection with MVVM Caliburn Micro

Tags: windows-phone-8, caliburn.micro

I'm using Caliburn.Micro and the LongListSelector. Because binding 
SelectedItem is a problem i'm create a Custom class

public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItem", typeof(object), typeof(LongListSelector),
        new PropertyMetadata(null, OnSelectedItemChanged));

Problem is, after returning to the list, when I click the same item again, it is already selected and not works.

I'm used a TAP event instead SelectionChanged and it Works but in my longlistselector i use a Grouping and Tap event click if i tap on group.

Help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Solved!! My problem was in a DependecyProperty declaration

```
private static void OnSelectedItemChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var selector = (LongListSelector)d;
        selector.SelectedItem = e.NewValue;
    }
```

NOT WORKS

WORKS This declaration

```
 private static void OnSelectedItemChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var selector = (LongListSelector)d;
        selector.SetSelectedItem(e);
    }

    private void SetSelectedItem(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.SelectedItem = e.NewValue;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting `SelectedItem=null` in `OnActivate` in your ViewModel should do the trick.

Comment: My problem was in a DependecyProperty declaration. Thank you for response